# Can Lighttpd listen to http://localhost when I change the default portnumber?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, localhost, lighttpd

Is it possible to let lighttpd listen to http://localhost (so no portnumber used in the URL) when I change my default portnumber?

I know this is possible when I use default port 80, but I added server.port = 8080 in my lighttpd config. Now I have to use http://localhost:8080 to access lighttpd. Is there an option to use http://localhost having port 8080 as my server port?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to let lighttpd listen to http://localhost (so no
>   portnumber used in the URL) when I change my default portnumber?

**No**, web servers listen only to the port(s) you've configured them to.

> Is there an option to use http://localhost having port 8080 as my
>   server port?

Yes, you can. As you've tagged this question with port-forwarding, I'm going to answer about that.

You can setup port forwarding from `localhost:80` to `localhost:8080`.
If the host is a router (considering it's `lighthttpd`..) you can configure this easily from the  control panel settings.
If the host is a Linux machine, you can configure this via `iptables`:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

This configures iptables to redirect all output traffic with destination port 80 to the loopback interface to port 8080.

---

Just a side note:
I don't see the reason in making the webserver **not** listen on port 80, just to make port forwarding from that port to the new http port. You have another option where you can configure the webserver to listen to both ports (80 and 8080), but serve the webpages only from port 8080. Then you can use port 80 and configure it in http to redirect everything from its virtualhost on port 80 to the virtualhost on port 8080.